# How to fix "Expected RBRACE"-error at media query?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make our web page device responsive with @media. However, I get the errors "Expected RBRACE at line 44, col 3." and "Unexpected token '}' at line 48 col 1.", even though the code looks fine to me. Does anyone have a solution to this?

I've tried to fix the code according to the errors, but that just messes up the @media-portion of the code totally. I've also ran the code through code examiners and the errors remain.

```
.content {
  font-family: 'Lora', sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  @media (min-width: 480px) {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
 }
```

My goal is to put the code above in css and then use

```
<div class="content">text goes here</div>
```

to make our texts look better. However, because of the errors in the css, the div class-line does not have any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot nest a `@media` query inside vanilla css like this.

You should re-write your css to look like this:

```
/* outside the media query */

.content {
    font-family: 'Lora', sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .content{
        width: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Only replace rules where necessary. This will reduce the amount of code you have to write. Also, have a look at https://sass-lang.com/, it will make writing css much easier!

As a general rule of thumb, I tend to place all my `@media` rules at either the bottom of the stylesheet or in another stylesheet. The idea is that you specify the generic rules at the top of the page (like `font-size`, `font-family`, `width`, etc) then only when you need to, specify what should change and at what viewpoint (like the code I have provided).

Let me know if this is unclear for you!

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

The code doesn't give any errors anymore, thanks for that! However, the responsiveness isn't working like I thought. I noticed I didn't really get my goal through in the post. 

What I'm trying to achieve is control the width of the text elements so that they don't spread so wide as they do now. The problem is that I would need the width to be responsive in a way that the text gets buffered when viewed with regular screens (desktop etc.) but stays unbuffered when viewed with mobile devices. This because the buffered text looks really narrow on mobile devices.

Comment: Hi konkala! Try adding some padding to the `.content`, like so: `.content { padding: 0 .5em; }`
Edit: You may also need to control `text-overflow` when `content` gets to a certain width on smaller devices. I feel like I've given you enough information to complete your task though, so the rest is up to you. Good luck.

Also, if you feel my answer is correct, please mark it so others can see it in future. Ta!